# Deep links to custom Tab - thread.skype vs thread.tacv2

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have problems with executing deep links created in a custom tab of my application in MS Teams.

I generate the link as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links
(the format of `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>?webUrl=<entityWebUrl>&label=<entityLabel>&context=<context>`)

while it works fine in environment A:
e.g
[https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/9263e4c8-.....-48293cfca89a/111-222?context={"channelId":"19:xxxxxx@thread.skype"}](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/9263e4c8-.....-48293cfca89a/111-222?context=%7B%22channelId%22:%2219:xxxxxx@thread.skype%22%7D)

it's not working in environment B (same app, another tenant) - it opens the correct team channel, but not the tab.
[https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/9263e4c8-.....-48293cfca89a/555-666?context={"channelId":"19:xxxxxx@thread.tacv2"}](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/9263e4c8-.....-48293cfca89a/555-666?context=%7B%22channelId%22:%2219:xxxxxx@thread.tacv2%22%7D)

I noticed the thread.skype vs thread.tacv2 in the channelId, could this make the difference? Am I missing some important query param? I double-checked the appId, entityID, they match.

Comment: Why is the entity id different, in your samples above (111-222 vs 555-666)? Also, are these definitely both channel tabs (vs a group chat tab)? Finally, one might be the 'general' channel, versus a 'sub' channel, which might explain the different format

Comment: it's not the same tab. As I understand it, the `entityId` is the id of the tab created by my application (with the appId `9263e4c8-.....-48293cfca89a` ). The app is running under different tenants, both have created their own tab with different entityId. MS Teams is able to open the correct tab when the deep link contains `appId`, `entityId` and `channelId` - unless there is the `tacv2` in the channelId

Comment: Is your tab contained in a regular Teams app (e.g. manifest file)? Or are you creating the tabs from Graph or something like that?

Comment: it's regular Teams app, with manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the upgrade manifest version fixed this issue (1.5 -> 1.7)

```
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.7/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion": "1.7",
```

with 1.7 links are working as expected